# Анимация svg в html

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

Как сделать анимацию такую же как на https://aviapark.com/ при наведении на блоки [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что уже сделано и что не получается ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно навесить на svg id'шник, а потом выполнить магию:

```
@keyframe animation1 {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(n,n,n);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate3d(k,k,k);
  }
}

@keyframe animation2 {
  from {
    transform: translate3d(k,k,k);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate3d(n,n,n);
  }
}

#animatedElement1 path {
  animation: animation1 2s ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards:
}

#animatedElement1:hover path {
  animation: animation2 2s ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards:
}
```

`n, k` - вычисляются обычно опытным путем